# jquery animate top doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating three rectangles as follows. I want to make it so when I click the `close` button on the right side of rectangles, it disappears (I already done it) and every rectangles under it moves upward to fill the empty spaces (I still have a problem with it). So far I already tried this

```
$(".note-content-right").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("note-float-view");
  var thisDataIndex = $(this).parent().attr("data-index");
  $(".note-float").each(function() {
    if(($(this).hasClass("note-float-view")) && ($(this).attr("data-index") > thisDataIndex)) {
      $(this).animate({
        "top" : "-=54px"
      });
    };
  });
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated! :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".note-float").removeClass("note-under");
  loadNote();
});

function loadNote() {
  $(".note-float").each(function(index) {
    var el = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function () {
      el.addClass("note-float-view");
    }, index * 200);
  });
}

function unloadNote() {
  $(".note-float-view").each(function(index) {
    var el = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function () {
      el.removeClass("note-float-view");
    }, index * 200);
  });
}

$(".note-content-right").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("note-float-view");
  var thisDataIndex = $(this).parent().attr("data-index");
  $(".note-float").each(function() {
    if(($(this).hasClass("note-float-view")) && ($(this).attr("data-index") > thisDataIndex)) {
      $(this).animate({
        "top" : "-=54px"
      });
    };
  });
});

$(".load-note").click(function() {
  $(".note-float").removeClass("note-under");
  $(".note-float").removeClass("note-float-view");
  setTimeout(function() {
    loadNote();
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.note-float-view {
  top: 24px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: top 1s, margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.note {
  padding: 14px 8px 14px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 auto 48px;
  display: table;
  width: 768px;
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.note-float {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: top 1s, margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.note-content-left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 32px; 
}

.note-content-center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
}

.note-content-right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.info {
  background-color: #CAF1FF;
  color: #0099ff;
  border: solid 1px #B1DEFF;
}

.success {
  background-color: #DAFDDC;
  color: #117250;
}

.warning {
  background-color: #F8F2D7;
  color: #DD6F1E;
}

.error {
  background-color: #FFE2E2; 
  color: #E9190C;
}

i.fa-info-circle {
  color: #0099ff;
}

i.fa-puzzle-piece,
.close-warning {
  color: #DD6F1E;
}

i.fa-check-circle,
.close-success {
  color: #117250;
}

i.fa-times-circle,
.close-error {
  color: #E9190C;
}

.note-content-right > .fa-times {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 12px; 
}

.dropdown-for-note {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 366px;
}

.select-info {
  top: 8px;
  width: 366px;
}

.load-note {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
}

.load-note:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.note-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.select-caption {
  margin-top: 24px; 
}

.load-btn-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 48px;
}

.form-unit {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .note {
    width: calc(100% - 32px); 
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .select-info {
    width: 366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .note,
  .select-info {
    width: calc(100% - 32px); 
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="note-wrapper">

  
  <div class="note note-float success" data-index="1">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      You have successfully added <b>1 item(s)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-success"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="note note-float warning" data-index="2">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      You have successfully deleted <b>1 item(s)</b>, but failed to delete <b>1 item(s)</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-warning"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="note note-float error" data-index="3">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      <b>BPJS TK:</b> Data is used on other module
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-error"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="load-btn-wrapper">
    <a class="button white-btn footer-btn load-note">Reload </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using positioning on these? If you left these in the standard DOM flow, you wouldn't need to reposition. When deleting one, the other would automatically move up...

Comment: @Chris I already tried adding class with `display: none` to deleted rectangle. Of course the others move up, but not in a pleasant way (not smoothly). It's my main concern actually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `top: 24px !important;` on `.note-float-view` is overriding the animation.  Removing the `!important` is sufficient.

I've also updated the 'reset' function to set all the items' top back to 24px instead of wherever the animation happens to have left it.  (It may be better to do this on individual items at the end of the animation itself, though.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".note-float").removeClass("note-under");
  loadNote();
});

function loadNote() {
  $(".note-float").each(function(index) {
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.addClass("note-float-view");
    }, index * 200);
  });
}

function unloadNote() {
  $(".note-float-view").each(function(index) {
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.removeClass("note-float-view");
    }, index * 200);
  });
}

$(".note-content-right").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("note-float-view");
  var thisDataIndex = $(this).parent().attr("data-index");
  $(".note-float").each(function() {
    if (($(this).hasClass("note-float-view")) && ($(this).attr("data-index") > thisDataIndex)) {
      $(this).animate({
        "top": "-=54px"
      });
    };
  });
});

$(".load-note").click(function() {
  $(".note-float")
    .removeClass("note-under")
    .removeClass("note-float-view")
    .css("top","24px");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    loadNote();
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.note-float-view {
  top: 24px ;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: top 1s, margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.note {
  padding: 14px 8px 14px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 auto 48px;
  display: table;
  width: 768px;
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.note-float {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  transition: top 1s, margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.note-content-left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 32px;
}

.note-content-center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
}

.note-content-right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
  background-color: #CAF1FF;
  color: #0099ff;
  border: solid 1px #B1DEFF;
}

.success {
  background-color: #DAFDDC;
  color: #117250;
}

.warning {
  background-color: #F8F2D7;
  color: #DD6F1E;
}

.error {
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
  color: #E9190C;
}

i.fa-info-circle {
  color: #0099ff;
}

i.fa-puzzle-piece,
.close-warning {
  color: #DD6F1E;
}

i.fa-check-circle,
.close-success {
  color: #117250;
}

i.fa-times-circle,
.close-error {
  color: #E9190C;
}

.note-content-right>.fa-times {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.dropdown-for-note {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 366px;
}

.select-info {
  top: 8px;
  width: 366px;
}

.load-note {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.load-note:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.note-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.caption {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.select-caption {
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.load-btn-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 48px;
}

.form-unit {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .note {
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
  .select-info {
    width: 366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .note,
  .select-info {
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="note-wrapper">


  <div class="note note-float success" data-index="1">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      You have successfully added <b>1 item(s)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-success"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="note note-float warning" data-index="2">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      You have successfully deleted <b>1 item(s)</b>, but failed to delete <b>1 item(s)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-warning"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="note note-float error" data-index="3">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      <b>BPJS TK:</b> Data is used on other module
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-error"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="load-btn-wrapper">
    <a class="button white-btn footer-btn load-note">Reload </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

As a side note, the hardcoded 54px amount by which you're animating the position doesn't work if the text inside these items wraps to another line. You might instead want to capture the height of the removed element and then animate by that amount from the following elements.

In general it's best to avoid hardcoding pixel values whenever possible, and avoid depending on absolute positioning if you can, because it tends to involve a lot of fiddly repositioning like this.  If you depend on the document flow instead, the browser will do most of that work for you.   For this case, for example, I'd remove elements by animating their max-height down to zero (with a hidden overflow-y); then you wouldn't need to do any manual positioning at all.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! One little problem is, can I make it so the position resets when I click the reload button on the bottom? Using your code edits, when I click reload, the deleted rectangle just disappears..

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of the problem with depending on absolute positioning; you'll have to reset the positions of all the elements in that reset function.